# How to install parent project automatically in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, maven-3

I am using maven 3.1.0. My projects are:

- core
- web-project-1
- web-project-2

The core project is a parent for both web projects. So I specified this in maven by using `<parent>` tag.

The thing I would like to achieve is to install `core` automatically every time I deploy my web applications just to be sure all changed in this project are included and deployed. I work on appengine environment so I use `appengine:devserver` goal to run it.

I know I can aggregate modules from the parent POM. But even with this I have to remember to click `install` on the parent project.

I just want to do something like [install on core] and [appengine:devserver on web-project] in one operation.

Answer (score -1):

Create an appropriate folder structure like this:

```
  root (pom.xml)
   +-- core (pom.xml)
   +-- web-project1 (pom.xml)
   +-- web-project2 (pom.xml)
```

mention the core, web-project1 etc. in the parent pom (root) and define appropriate dependencies between the modules so you can do the whole install from root folder as this:

```
mvn clean install
```

That's it.

Comment: yes, I know, but I would like to avoid additional clicking on core or another project when I deploy my web project. In other words, I just want to do something like (install on core) and (appengine:devserver on web-project) in one operation.

Comment: If you correctly configure your plugins this will work...but i don't know how your pom files look like and what exactly you like to achieve...you go to root and do `mvn install`?

Comment: yest this works (if I use aggregation) when I install parent. But the question is how to automatically install parent by clicking install on a child (not a child while installing parent)

Comment: Installing a parent if your starting in the child does not work...or i do misunderstand you question...

Comment: Change into the root and make the `mvn install` ... ?

Comment: how can I deploy the project then?.. yes I know I can change to the child and deploy .. but I would like to done it automatically in one operation not two.